# How to set my view in OpenGL ES 2.0 to show exactly the right number of coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing a simple 2D game for Android with a 300x200 play area with coords running from (0,0 to 299,199). I'd want this area to fill the screen as best as possible while maintaining its aspect ratio. e.g. if the GL view fills the full 800x480 of a device I could scale the area by 2.4x to 720x480 leaving 40 pixels of space either side.

I don't expect many devices would exactly scale in both dimensions so the code has to cope with a gap either in the horizontal or vertical.

So the question is how do I do this. My play area is 2D so I can use an orthgraphic projection. I just don't understand what values I need to plug in to set this up. I also suspect that because ES 2.0 has a heavy reliance on shaders that I might need to propagate some kind of scaling matrix to a vector shader to ensure objects are rendered to the right size.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial which perhaps talks in terms that make sense for my needs? Most tutorials I've seen seem content to dump a cube or square into the middle of the screen rather than rendering an area of exact dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

These problem should be easy using the old and familiar Opengl functions, like glViewport and glProjection. GLM offers that for enviroments like Opengl ES, have a look

http://glm.g-truc.net/